# Why in doing PCA, scikit-learn use svd to get eigenvalue while the traditional method is to use eig?

Tags: scikit-learn, pca

While I'm doing PCA with scikit-learn, I found that it uses svd to get `eigenvalue` and `eigenvector`, and then use `svd_flip` to get real eigenvector.

And here's my code to get `eigenvalue` and `eigenvector`.

```
pca = PCA(data.shape[1])
newData = pca.fit_transform(data)
eigenvalue, eigenvector = np.linalg.eig(np.cov(data.transpose()))
explained_variance_ratio_sum_ = np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)

index = eigenvalue.argsort()[::-1]
eigenvalue = eigenvalue[index]
eigenvector = eigenvector[:, index]
```

Why sklearn uses svd? Are there any pros or cons? And I'm not quite familiar with the `svd_flip` function, would you show me the usage of it?

Many thanks.

Comment: This may not be the right place for discussion of algorithms. Please have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79043/why-pca-of-data-by-means-of-svd-of-the-data

Answer (score 0):

The SVD-based method used by scikit-learn does not have to materialize the empirical covariance matrix in memory and therefore is more memory efficient.

From a compute time point of view it should be quite similar although I have not checked.